# BASH - how can i search a value from whole directory and find some matched value, then on the fly replace that line by saving it

Tags: linux, perl, bash, sed, awk

I have under `/var/tmp/`   following random `.xml` files and there i have such lines containing:  `cidr=x.x.x.x/32` or `x.x.x.x` only, now i need to search for a IP and replace them like add/edit/del.

***Before:***

```
file1.xml: <user id="1" cidr="192.168.1.12">
file2.xml: <user id="2" cidr="192.168.1.12,192.168.1.13">
file3.xml: <user id="3" cidr="8.8.8.8">
file4.xml: <user id="4" cidr="8.8.8.8/32">
fileX.xml: <user id="5" cidr="192.168.1.12/32">
```

***After*** (Expected output):

```
file1.xml: <user id="1" >
file2.xml: <user id="2" cidr="192.168.1.13">
file3.xml: <user id="3" cidr="8.8.8.8">
file4.xml: <user id="4" cidr="8.8.8.8/32">
fileX.xml: <user id="5" >
```

Now, to find which line contain matched ip and then replace it, i was trying in one line like something:

```
grep -R 'cidr=' ./*.xml              # search in whole directory
| awk '/192.168.1.12/ {print $1}'    # find for a given search criteria 
| sed 's/^.\///g'                    # replace some not necessary values
| sed 's/://'                        # ..
| xargs sed -i s/""/""/ /var/tmp/    # on the fly workout on that line 
                                     # + save it to that file
```

OR

```
grep -R 'cidr=' ./*.xml              # search in whole directory
| awk '/192.168.1.12/ {print $1}'    # find for a given search criteria 
| sed 's/^.\///g'                    # replace some not necessary values
| sed 's/://'                        # ..
| ( grep -R 'cidr=' ./*.xml 
    | awk '/192.168.1.12/ {print $4}' 
    | sed 's/ //g' 
  ) 
| xargs sed -i s/""/""/ /var/tmp/    # on the fly workout on that line 
                                     # + save it to that file
```

But not seems to work like expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this line works for your example:

```
grep...|awk '{gsub(/192.168.1.12[^,"]*[,"]/,"");sub(/cidr=">/,">")}7'
```

little test:

```
kent$  cat f
file1.xml: <user id="1" cidr="192.168.1.12">
file2.xml: <user id="2" cidr="192.168.1.12,192.168.1.13">
file3.xml: <user id="3" cidr="8.8.8.8">
file4.xml: <user id="4" cidr="8.8.8.8/32">
fileX.xml: <user id="5" cidr="192.168.1.12/32">
kent$  awk '{gsub(/192.168.1.12[^,"]*[,"]/,"");sub(/cidr=">/,">")}7' f
file1.xml: <user id="1" >
file2.xml: <user id="2" cidr="192.168.1.13">
file3.xml: <user id="3" cidr="8.8.8.8">
file4.xml: <user id="4" cidr="8.8.8.8/32">
fileX.xml: <user id="5" >
```

Comment: I think that those prefix mean different files with `xml` data, and that they are not part of the file. But better the user say something because it's not completely clear for me.

Comment: @Birei I think it is output from OP's `grep` call. I created the file `f` just for simulating the input of awk... I hope I understood the problem right.

Comment: @Birei Oh, I read his codes twice, I think you maybe right! he wants to in place change the string in xml files...

Comment: YES - its perfect, but what i wanted to do is like `grep .. | awk .. | xargs sed -i replace /var/tmp/save to that file.xml`

Comment: As you mentioned, it will work with the posted input. It won't work with other input, though, e.g. when the target IP address comes 2nd in a list of IP addresses instead of first, or when there's an IP address that has one extra digit (e.g. 192.168.1.123) or when there's a string like "789192316841512187763" elsewhere in the input (not anchoring the IP addr and escaping the `.` RE metacharacters). See the sample input I used in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need half a dozen pipes and various commands, just use find to find the files and awk to modify them, e.g.:

```
find /var/tmp/ -type f -name '*.xml' -print |
while IFS= read -r file
do
    awk '
        <whatever>
    ' "$file" > tmp$$ && mv tmp$$ "$file"
done
```

and here's a way to write the awk script:

```
$ cat file
file1.xml: <user id="1" cidr="192.168.1.12">
file1.xml: <user id="1" cidr="192.168.1012">
file1.xml: <user id="1" cidr="192.168.1.123">
file2.xml: <user id="2" cidr="192.168.1.12,192.168.1.13">
file2.xml: <user id="2" cidr="192.168.1.13,192.168.1.12">
file2.xml: <user id="2" cidr="192.168.1.13,192.168.1.12,8.8.8.8">
file3.xml: <user id="3" cidr="8.8.8.8">
file4.xml: <user id="4" cidr="8.8.8.8/32">
fileX.xml: <user id="5" cidr="192.168.1.12/32">

$ awk -v tgtIp="192.168.1.12" '
BEGIN {
    gsub(/\./,"\\.",tgtIp)
    tgtIp  = tgtIp "(/[[:digit:]]+)?"
    tgtIp = "(," tgtIp "\\>)|(\\<" tgtIp ",)|(\\<" tgtIp "\\>)"
}
match($0,tgtIp) {
    $0 = substr($0,1,RSTART-1) substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    sub(/cidr=""/,"")
}
{ print }
' file
file1.xml: <user id="1" >
file1.xml: <user id="1" cidr="192.168.1012">
file1.xml: <user id="1" cidr="192.168.1.123">
file2.xml: <user id="2" cidr="192.168.1.13">
file2.xml: <user id="2" cidr="192.168.1.13">
file2.xml: <user id="2" cidr="192.168.1.13,8.8.8.8">
file3.xml: <user id="3" cidr="8.8.8.8">
file4.xml: <user id="4" cidr="8.8.8.8/32">
fileX.xml: <user id="5" >
```

so the whole shell script would be:

```
find /var/tmp/ -type f -name '*.xml' -print |
while IFS= read -r file
do
    awk -v tgtIp="192.168.1.12" '
    BEGIN {
        gsub(/\./,"\\.",tgtIp)
        tgtIp  = tgtIp "(/[[:digit:]]+)?"
        tgtIp = "(," tgtIp "\\>)|(\\<" tgtIp ",)|(\\<" tgtIp "\\>)"
    }
    match($0,tgtIp) {
        $0 = substr($0,1,RSTART-1) substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
        sub(/cidr=""/,"")
    }
    { print }
    ' "$file" > tmp$$ && mv tmp$$ "$file"
done
```

You might want to try any other solutions you're considering with the sample input I used above.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged Perl

```
ls *xml | xargs script.pl
```

Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use strict;
use warnings;
my $ip = '192.168.1.12' ;
foreach my $file (@ARGV)
{
    open(FILE,$file);
    while(<FILE>)
    {
        s/(cidr="$ip\/32"|cidr="$ip"|$ip,)//;
        print "$file: $_";
    }
    close(FILE);
}
```